# PY Chatbot Repeating user input prompt

Tags: python, python-3.x, chatbot

New to Python here. I've been coding a small chatbot for a while now, and when I prompt the user to enter something instead of answering with the correct response the bot just repeats the prompt. Everything before that works just fine, but it gets stuck in a loop of asking the user for an input.

````
print("Hello " + User_Name + """. 
Tonic is a simple Python chatbot made in order to test things such as boolean logic
and variable definition.
(Also remember to speak to the bot in lowercase, without punctuation.)""")
while 1 == 1:
str1 = input("Say something: ")
#"hello" //////////////////////////////////////////
if "hello" in str1:
print("Hi " + User_Name + "! (I read this as the 'hello' greeting.");
#"hi" //////////////////////////////////////////
if "hi" in str1:
print("Hi " + User_Name + "! (I read this as the 'hi' greeting.");
#"how are you?" //////////////////////////////////////////
if "how are you" in str1:
print("good, how about you? (I read this as you asking 'how are you'.)")
mood = input("Enter Mood: ")
if "good" in mood:
   print("Nice to hear " + User_Name + "! (I read this as you being in a good mood.)");
if "bad" in mood:
   print("I hope you feel better soon, " + User_Name + "! (I read this as you being in a bad mood.)");
#"name length" //////////////////////////////////////////
if "name length" in str1:
print( "Your name is " + len(User_Name) + "letters long. (I read this as you asking how long your name is.");```
````

Comment: Please fix the indentation of the shown code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your while loop does not have an exit condition. It will repeat forever since 1
is always equal to 1.
Instead, you could do `while (str1 != "quit")` which would stop the while loop once the user enters "quit" in the prompt.

Also, side note, you should not be using semicolons at the end of lines in Python.

```py
print("Hello " + User_Name + """. 
Tonic is a simple Python chatbot made in order to test things such as boolean logic
and variable definition.
(Also remember to speak to the bot in lowercase, without punctuation.)""")
while (str1 != "quit"): # You need an exit condition here
    str1 = input("Say something: ")
    #"hello" //////////////////////////////////////////
    if "hello" in str1:
        print("Hi " + User_Name + "! (I read this as the 'hello' greeting.")
    #"hi" //////////////////////////////////////////
    if "hi" in str1:
        print("Hi " + User_Name + "! (I read this as the 'hi' greeting.")
    #"how are you?" //////////////////////////////////////////
    if "how are you" in str1:
        print("good, how about you? (I read this as you asking 'how are you'.)")
        mood = input("Enter Mood: ")
        if "good" in mood:
            print("Nice to hear " + User_Name + "! (I read this as you being in a good mood.)")
        if "bad" in mood:
            print("I hope you feel better soon, " + User_Name + "! (I read this as you being in a bad mood.)")
    #"name length" //////////////////////////////////////////
    if "name length" in str1:
        print( "Your name is " + len(User_Name) + "letters long. (I read this as you asking how long your name is.")
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Fix indentation
2. Convert output from len into string

```
print("Hello " + User_Name + """. 
Tonic is a simple Python chatbot made in order to test things such as boolean logic
and variable definition.
(Also remember to speak to the bot in lowercase, without punctuation.)""")
while 1 == 1:
    str1 = input("Say something: ")
    #"hello" //////////////////////////////////////////
    if "hello" in str1:
        print("Hi " + User_Name + "! (I read this as the 'hello' greeting.");
        
    #"hi" //////////////////////////////////////////
    if "hi" in str1:
        print("Hi " + User_Name + "! (I read this as the 'hi' greeting.");
    #"how are you?" //////////////////////////////////////////
    if "how are you" in str1:
        print("good, how about you? (I read this as you asking 'how are you'.)")
    mood = input("Enter Mood: ")
    if "good" in mood:
       print("Nice to hear " + User_Name + "! (I read this as you being in a good mood.)");
    if "bad" in mood:
       print("I hope you feel better soon, " + User_Name + "! (I read this as you being in a bad mood.)");
    #"name length" //////////////////////////////////////////
    if "name length" in str1:
        print( "Your name is " + str(len(User_Name)) + "letters long. (I read this as you asking how long your name is.");
```

Answer (score 0):

i just found a module which you can create a chatbot with just a handful lines of code
refer to this https://pypi.org/project/prsaw/
or

```
from prsaw import RandomStuff

random = RandomStuffV2()

str1 = input("message: ")

response = random.get_ai_response(str1)
print(response)
```

Comment: It is not working, see [This problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72803637/getting-keyerror-in-prsaw)